# Differences between open() and path.open()

Tags: python, path

Regarding the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module in the standard library, is the [`path.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) method is just a "wrapper" for built-in `open()` function?

Comment: @MikahilZakharov, are you referring to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) library?

Comment: @toti08 Yes, you are right.

Comment: Open the file pointed to by the path, *like the built-in open() function does* – does that answer your question? Whether you consider it as a wrapper, you can decide by looking at the source code of pathlib.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have read the doc, you are quoting and actually my question was inspired by exactly this remark. Yes, I can look into sources and, but I thought maybe someone already knows the answer without looking into the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pathlib.py#L1167) of `pathlib.Path.open` you'll find that it simply does:

```
return io.open(str(self), mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline, opener=self._opener)
```

and according to [`io`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open):

> `io.open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`
>
> This is an alias for the builtin `open()` function.

So you are correct that `pathlib.Path.open` is just a wrapper for the built-in `open` function.